# Uploading... forever

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading

This is my code:

```
const int trigPin = 4;
const int echoPin = 2;
const int trigPin2 = 6;
int incomingByte;
int val, val2;
const int echoPin2 = 7;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, LOW);

  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);

  val = digitalRead(echoPin);
  val2 = digitalRead(echoPin2);

  if (val && val2 == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Elephant on tracks");
  }


  if (Serial.available() > 0) {  // if the data came
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
  }
  // read byte
  if(incomingByte == '0') {
     digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);  
     digitalWrite(trigPin2, LOW);
     Serial.println("The system is OFF.");  // print message
  }
}
```

Anyhow, I click upload, and as the title of this question says, have to wait forever.
Not only this code, nothing gets uploaded. It was working just fine a week ago.
I run a Windows 7 64-bit system, and have an Arduino Uno R3. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: So you can't upload the sketch to Arduino? No error messages at all? Try to enable the verbose options in settings and paste the result here

Comment: Are you uploading to the right serial port? Do you have anything else attached to the Arduino?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It finally worked. It was because of my HC-06 Bluetooth module. I don't know if the mistake was mine or if it is a fault with the module.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I assume that the bluetooth module is connected to pins 0 & 1 on the arduino. These pins are to be kept free/floating/not connected to anything if you need to upload code to your board.

Use software serial in such cases reduces the headache

Answer (score 0):

*Comment by SR1 turned into an answer*:

Thanks for the suggestions. It finally worked. It was because of my HC-06 Bluetooth module. I don't know if the mistake was mine or if it is a fault with the module.

---

(Done to reduce "unanswered questions" on this site).